# Shaking a div on loop

Tags: jquery

I'm using the below code; but I would simply like it to pause, for maybe like 500 or half a second; and then continue on loop. I'm wondering how or if I can edit my current implemented snippet to handle this.

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({ "position" : "relative" });
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            $(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
        }
    });
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section7").shake();
});
```

Comment: I would use [CSS](https://daneden.me/animate/).

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ },2000) for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the counter on the for loop to some large number and then add a delay at the end of the animate function. I repeated the animation 3 times to coincide with your original animate function:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
  this.each(function(i) {
  $(this).css({ "position" : "relative" });
  for (var x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        $(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
        $(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
        $(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 20).delay(500);
  }
  });
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this with a jQuery plugin would be to add a callback, and then use a recursive function or a loop to fire the plugin as many times you'd want

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(callback) {
    this.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({ "position" : "relative" });
        var promises = [];
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            var ani =$(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10)
                   .animate({ left: 0 }, 50)
                   .animate({ left: 15 }, 10)
                   .animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
            promises.push(ani);
        }
        $.when.apply(undefined,promises).then(callback)
    });
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    (function recursive() {
        $("#section7").shake(function() {
            setTimeout(recursive, 500);
        });
    })();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PqyfU/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do stuff like `delay(millis);`.
You can do it after the for cycle or just add it between animations `$(this).animate(/*some code*/).delay(/*time in millis*/).animate(/*some other code*/);`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it through a call to `window.setTimeout`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gRwU/)

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i, elem) {
        $(this).css({ "position" : "relative" });
        var counter = 1;
        var jiggle = function() {
           $(elem).animate(
                               { left: -15 }, 
                               10
                           )
                   .animate({ left: 0 }, 50)
                   .animate({ left: 15 }, 10)
                   .animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
            if(++counter <= 3) {
                window.setTimeout(jiggle, 1000);
            }
        }
        jiggle();
    });
    return this;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section7").shake();
});
```